# FileNotFoundException with Java using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, file, io, filenotfoundexception

I am using Eclipse and am in the early stages of learning Java

Busy learning how to read data from a txt file but can't for the life of me get Java to read the my source file

Here is my code

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class MagellanSchoolQ2Coursework2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner detailsIn =new Scanner(new FileReader("c:\\s.txt"));
    detailsIn.close();
}
```

}

The text file is sitting in the root directory of my C drive but for some reason I get a FileNotFoundException

Does anyone know why this is not working

Comment: Do you have the appropriate permissions? Read the exception error message.

Comment: By permissions are you referring to Windows admin permissions?

Comment: This is the error I get:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException

 at MagellanSchoolQ2Coursework2.main(MagellanSchoolQ2Coursework2.java:9)

Comment: Then this is a compile error. Eclipse should have highlighted the error for you

Comment: The problem I am having is that the file is there in the root of my c drive but it's not being picked up by the compiler

Comment: If you are just starting to learn java you could put the s.txt file in the root folder of your project and use `Scanner detailsIn =new Scanner(new FileReader("s.txt"));` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must either surround your method with a `try/catch` or add a `throws` clause to your method.

E.g.

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MagellanSchoolQ2Coursework2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner detailsIn =new Scanner(new FileReader("c:\\s.txt"));
            detailsIn.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("file not found: s.txt");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: <code>import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MagellanSchoolQ2Coursework2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Scanner detailsIn =new Scanner(new FileReader("c:\\s.txt"));
            detailsIn.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("file not found: s.txt");
        }
        
        while (detailsIn.hasNextLine())
        {
        System.out.println(detailsIn.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
</code>

Error: detailsIn cannot be resolved

Comment: @user3002988 you can't use your `detailsIn` variable outside `try` block

Comment: Yes, this help. I work many years with c# and I cannot believe if java enforces try / catch for reading file. But java do not support real properties, or many usable functionalities. Unbelievable - java check application file existence during compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the constructor which you are using for creating a FileReader instance ,It's signature is as shown below

public FileReader(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException

Creates a new FileReader, given the name of the file to read from.

Parameters:   fileName - the name of the file to read from

Throws:  FileNotFoundException - if the named file does not exist, is a directory rather than a regular file, or for some other reason cannot be opened for reading.

**As this method throws "FileNotFoundException" it should be handled using try and catch blocks  (or) the main method should throw the above exception which will be handled by JVM during run time.If you are new to EXCEPTIONS study that topic better first and after that try learning I/O streams.**

Comment: Thanks and noted. Makes complete sense now.

Answer (score 0):

This is an operating system problem, I think. Because I use this form in Linux: "c:\s.txt", but in Windows I use it in a little bit different version: "c:\s.txt" Let's try it! :)

Comment: It is not true. Java has nothing to check the existence of the file during compilation.

Answer (score 0):

You could check this out: http://www.caveofprogramming.com/frontpage/articles/java/java-file-reading-and-writing-files-in-java/

Its actually very helpful